How Dump Tubes (arrangement with lot of perforation) reduces the pressure of Steam flow. How to derive a scientific basis of designing a dump tube
Recently I have come across simple yet intriguing device - The steam dump pipe with multiple perforations (orifices).
The dump pipe is typically used to reduce the steam flow pressure. The inlet steam comes at a steady rate (say 6 Tons per Hour). The dump pipe either at times can be enclosed in a larger diameter Pipe or is directly fixed in surface steam condensers, effectively meaning steam escapes to larger volume.

I am intrigued and want to know:

How this simple perforated device reduces pressure in a controlled manner.
Basis of designing a dump steam pipe device and deriving number of holes (orific) required/length

Governing Equations
Orifice Flow Modelling
Boundary Conditions
Simplifications vs. Accuracy
effect of various pattern of holes.



I have gone through some literature, such as DESIGN OF STEAM DUMP DEVICE
But not very sure of the calculations presented.
I have tried, mass balance and energy balance (enthalpy) but something seems amiss.

I think Joule-Thomson effect is involved.

@TomášLétal Thanks for the inputs. Any clue for how we can utilise the mentioned effect in designing the subject Equipment?

By Bernoulli's principle when source and dump pipe are at about the same height, pressure drops when velocity increases.
It is well known that leaks in a pressure vessel causes pressure drop and so a perforated vessel causes much higher pressure losses.
$$ p_1+\frac12 \rho v_1^2 = p_2+\frac12 \rho v_2^2 =p_2+\frac{\rho}{2} \left(\frac{Q}{A}\right)^2 $$
where $Q$ is flow rate, $A$ total orifice area,neglecting friction losses.There is reduction of pressure at Vena Contracta before partial recovery.
Induced Flow loss in Pipe Dump

Don't think this will be right way to look into it. With Steam, its heat content (enthalpy) calculation should to accounted for. Besides the setup of orifice is completely different, its not a Vena Contracta. Also the goal is calculating the number of holes required for a specific pressure drop!

Ok, referred to incompressible fluid flow mainly. In rocket nozzles a reduced throat is provided to expand a gas/vapour and design of Laval nozzles is available, we should consider enthalpy of many small nozzles/orifices. (Vena Contacta is seen more in liquids).
